# Position of an active MRTK 3 pointer

Tags: hololens, mrtk

Since MRTK 3 architecture has been redesigned based on XRI, porting MRTK 2 application is a little confusing especially how to get the coordinates of an active Pointer or controller. For MRTK 2, one could use ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56067810/how-do-i-get-the-position-of-an-active-mrtk-pointer))

MRTK 3 sample scenes don't really have any example how to deal with active pointer. I tried to use XRBasedInteractor but not getting the expected result.